# Query returns NULL - Oracle

Tags: oracle, query, parameter

I've an `Oracle` query where I need to get some data on the basis of some records (strings). I am using `IN` clause and query is working fine in `TOAD` with hardcoded data. But when I run that query through code (`Dapper`) and pass those strings as Parameters, query always returns NULL/ Empty result.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN :lstIds
```

that's how I'm passing my data as parameter:

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new DBManager().connection)
        {
            conn.Open();

            lstData = conn.Query<ViewModelData>(sqlGetData, new
            {
                lstIds = lstIdsParams

            }).ToList();

                conn.Dispose();
        }
```

and this is my list of Ids, that I am passing as param

[image]

Even if I run this query with hardcoded data, it still does not work..

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN 'PL-0417-01301006-H01-D-00013#000013#18'
```

But if I run same query in TOAD with hardcoded data, it works fine and returns proper data. I don't know what I am doing wrong in code that is creating issue. Can anyone help me out here??

Comment: *Here is my query* I think that your strings list is converted to one string literal, i.e. you obtain `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('v1, v2, v3')` instead of `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('v1', 'v2', 'v3')`...

Comment: How can I change it?

Comment: You must parse CSV which is transferred into the query to separate rows one value per row. I don't know does Oracle have some special construction for this purposes. Anycase you may convert your CSV to JSON array (on the client, or in the query using proper REPLACE) and use [JSON_TABLE()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#CJAGJFEI) for parsing.

Comment: but even if I pass hardcoded values, it still does not work.. Please check updated question..

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong you need  parenthesis around the value(s)

Please remember not to post Images for data, queries and errors

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   
>   id VARCHAR(50)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ('PL4418.01301006-H01-D-03013O322241');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ( '04l801301006-I401•0013ccO27I0');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ( 'P104I8.013016-H0l-D0l3c60O22l1');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ( 'P104I8013016-I40l-D013c0c0224V');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ( 'P10418-013016-HO1-D-010X2141');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ('PL-0418-013016-H01-D-0132241');
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO table1
> VALUES
>   ( 'PL.5410.01301006-H0l-D.0201300022');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN ('P104I8013016-I40l-D013c0c0224V');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ID                             |
> | :----------------------------- |
> | P104I8013016-I40l-D013c0c0224V |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d45c5f9e656fd913ab27450bf5e5eef2)*